# display the text without the use of XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a simple little game. I would do in her dialogue with the character in the game.
Is it possible to display the text without the use of XML? I also want to be able to move my text to any location on the screen.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

to draw text: [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and the `drawText()` functions

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Sudoku example in the `Hello, Android` book. You can get the code from http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband/source_code. It uses the `drawText()` function like @apps said.